# Finding the same number at different indexes using ArrayList and user input

Tags: java, arraylist

I am currently trying to solve this coding problem of finding the same number at different indexes using ArrayList and user input (scanner). It keeps passing my tests but I know it is wrong since it is only listing one of the indexes that the number is in the list, instead of the different indexes where the number is also present. I was wondering if anyone can give me any advice or tips on how to solve this. Also, I know there are probably way faster ways to do this, but I am currently doing a java course where it introduces the basics so keep that in mind.

Thank you in advance!

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class IndexOf {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        while (true) {
            int input = Integer.valueOf(scanner.nextLine());
            if (input == -1) {
                break;
            }

            list.add(input);
        }

        System.out.println("");

        int number = Integer.valueOf(scanner.nextLine());

        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            int placeholder = list.get(i);
            if (number == list.get(i)) {
                System.out.println(number + " is at index " + i);
            }        
            if (placeholder == number)
                System.out.println(number + " is at index " + i);
        }        // implement here finding the indices of a number
    }
}
```

Comment: Just took it out! Added code using the ```, thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```java
search: for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++) {
    for(int j=i+1; j<list.size(); j++) {
        if(number == list.get(i) && number == list.get(j)) {
            System.out.println("Number is at indices: " + i + ", " + j);
            break search;
        }
    }
}
```